React app connection with V380 pro wireless with Local RTSP Server
I am developing an application that uses a drone to show a live video from the camera. In our case I bought this v380 pro wireless camera for this purpose. My problem is that I am developing the application on a local server ad using React js and MERN stack. I have a screen where I am supposed to show the video from the camera. Now as far as I have seen, the v380 pro comes with an application that connects with a local wifi to get the video from the camera. now my question is how do i stream the video from that camera into my react app? I have looked into it but Could not find any documentation or a project. Please guide me.
I was looking for a way that I could integrate a URL that will show camera's live stream but I could not find any.
